# Does the `new` operator always call the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

My question is influenced by Prof. Thomas Cormen's *second comment* on his [Quora answer](http://qr.ae/TUT5EX)<sup>$</sup>.

He says that the constructor carries out the following three tasks:

> 1. Allocates memory for the object.
> 2. Initializes the instance variables of the object, e.g., by implicitly calling **init** in Python. (I also emphasize that the **init** method should initialize not some, but all of the instance variables.)
> 3. Returns a reference to (i.e., address of) the object.

However, the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx) for C++<sup>*</sup> says that it is the `new` operator that does that:

> Allocates memory for an object or array of objects of type-name from the free store and returns a suitably typed, nonzero pointer to the object.

My question is, who is right?  Or, is there something more to it, perhaps like the `new` operator always calls the constructor, as suggested by a comment on the post?

Thanks.

<sup>$ Unfortunately, Quora does not have the option to copy the link for a comment - I can only do so for the answer.</sup>
<sup>* Although I say C++, I think it is also true for other languages like Java and C# (I am not 100% sure though).</sup>

Comment: Don't know why you think those two quotes are mutually exclusive :)

Comment: I don't think I'm seeing what you expected to share from your first link.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, sorry, I didn't get you.  I just used the link because I was quoting someone else.  I have actually copied what he says into my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the constructor called by 'new' operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472418/when-is-the-constructor-called-by-new-operator-in-c)

Comment: Perhaps the two passages are talking about different uses of the `new` keyword. There is [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and there are [`new expressions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). `operator new` allocates, doesn't call the constructor and can be overwritten, `new expressions` (usually) allocates with `operator new` and calls the constructor.

Comment: Further in the MSDN article: _"When new is used to allocate memory for a C++ class object, the object's constructor is called after the memory is allocated."_

Comment: @Rakete1111, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @P.K. Basically what Francois said :)

Comment: If constructors allocated the object's memory, placement new would be utterly broken.

Comment: @P.K. The context for that passage seems important, but I can't find your citation using the provided link.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, it is in the comments (the second comment to be precise).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences Between Python and C++ Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025913/differences-between-python-and-c-constructors)

Comment: Why can't a Python constructor works as the professor described, and C++ new operator and constructor works differently? I fail to see what comparing construction mecanisms between two languages achieves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search for `constructor` on the linked MSDN page, it says this:

> When `new` is used to allocate memory for a C++ class object, the object's constructor is called after the memory is allocated.

In other words, a constructor is called if one exists. If none exists, none is called.

Comment: Sorry, this confuses me.  If a constructor is not defined, then in Cormen's words, who (or what) will carry out the three tasks?

Comment: A class type's constructor is always called and must exist, otherwise using `new` would be ill-formed. Though, that constructor may be empty and implicitly generated.

Comment: A bit of clarify with "if none exists": A default constructor does exist.

Comment: @Ripi2 A default constructor might not exist (ex. `struct foo { foo() = delete; };`), but there must exist a constructor that matches the arguments provided to `new`.

Comment: @Ripi2, yes, then it makes sense to me.

Comment: @P.K. Non-class types in C++ don't have constructors. C++ also has *trivial* constructors that do nothing. If nothing initializes an object in C++, then it is illegal to read from it or copy it. (Illegal meaning that doing so results in **undefined behavior**.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter, okay, then that makes the number of activities of the constructor _two_.  What about the first task - memory allocation?  Is it done by `new` and not the constructor?  I think the quote in your answer subtly says this.

Comment: More clarify: There are trivial ctors. You can have several, overloaded, ctors. You can leave the compiler to create a default ctor. You can avoid this default creation. Use the best for each case-

Comment: @P.K. Memory allocation is done by a function named `operator new` (somewhat confusingly). Then the constructor is a separate call.

Comment: @P.K. The constructor may only be called after memory has been allocated. Conceptually, it can't be responsible for allocating that memory. It's the `new operator` for that class, which is called by the `new expression`, that allocates the memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thank you for the precise comment.  It is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, read the specification. From [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

> The new expression attempts to allocate storage and then **attempts to
>   construct and initialize** either a single unnamed object, or an unnamed
>   array of objects in the allocated storage. The new-expression returns
>   a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, if an array of objects
>   was constructed, a pointer to the initial element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor does not allocate memory. 
new allocates memory, then calls the proper constructor.

Semi pseudo code here :

```
template <typename T>
T* new(Args... arguments_to_constructor_of_T_if_any)
{
    void* mem = malloc(sizeof(T)); // Allocate memory 

    // Call constructor 
    // Compiler will produce machine code to construct object T over memory mem.
    (mem) T(arguments_to_constructor_of_T_if_any); 

    return (T*)(mem);
}
```

An example :

```
class A
{
   int a;
   int b;

   A(int a, int b) { this->a = a; this->b = b; };
}

int main() 
{
   A* a = new A(3, 4);

   // After compiled, code above will look like : 
   void* mem = malloc(sizeof(A));

   // Below is A(int, int) constructor
   ((T*) mem)-> a = 3;
   ((T*) mem)-> b = 4;
}
```